# I need to send a GPG message and I only have the pubkey of the recipients email

Tags: email, encryption, gpg

I have a Centos 7 on my desktop.

I have a public GPG key of an e-mail address where I need to send an e-mail.

**Question:** How can I send an encrypted e-mail to the recipient?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Unix but to GPG encryption specifically.

Comment: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html should answer your question.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. There seem to be two things it could be asking: "How do I get the email address associated with a PGP key using GPG?" (title); "How do I send an encrypted email with a known key and address using GPG?" (end). Both of those ask about the use of Unix software and are on-topic.

Comment: I am, however, voting to close as unclear until which question it's asking is clarified.

Comment: What email client do you use?

Answer (score 3):

1. Import the public GPG key `pubkey.asc`

   ```
   gpg --import < pubkey.asc
   ```
2. Find the key ID by listing your keys

   ```
   gpg --list-key
   pub   1234R/2A4E837B 2017-01-01
   uid                 John Smith  <john.smith@gmail.com>
   sub   2345R/12345BC7 2017-01-01
   ```

the public key ID is here `2A4E837B`

3. Write your message in a file `mymessage.txt` and encrypt it by giving the ID

   ```
   gpg -e -a mymessage.txt

   Enter the user ID.  End with an empty line:  [ press "2A4E837" and "ENTER"]
   Enter the user ID.  End with an empty line:  [ press "ENTER" ]
   ```
4. A new file `mymessage.txt.asc`  has been created. Use any mail service to send its content to your recipient.